# Flutter error: RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded

Tags: flutter

I want to have a `GridView.builder` inside another `TabBar` Widget of `SingleChildScrollView` and I got this error.

```
======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
```

I tried to put the GridView in a Container and give a specific height, it doesn't make an error but the Grid was cut off.

This is my SingleChildScrollView Widget code

```
import ...

class CommunityPage extends StatefulWidget {...}

class _CommunityPageState extends State<CommunityPage> {
  ScrollController? sc;
  bool check = false;

  Future<void> _copyToClipboard() async {...}

  @override
  void initState() {...}

  @override
  void dispose() {...}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0.0,
        ),
        drawer: const SideBar(),
        floatingActionButton: check
            ? FloatingActionButton.small(...)
            : null,
        floatingActionButtonAnimator: FloatingActionButtonAnimator.scaling,
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: ((this.sc == null) && !this.sc!.hasClients)
              ? const Center(...)
              : SingleChildScrollView(
                  controller: this.sc!,
                  child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(...),
                        const SizedBox(height: largeSpace * 0.8),
                        Row(...),
                        const SizedBox(height: 20),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 65.0),
                          child: Container(
                            height: 43,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(...),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                              child: TabBar(
                                indicator: BoxDecoration(),
                                labelColor: Colors.white,
                                unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
                                tabs: const [
                                  Tab(
                                    child: Text(
                                      'EVENTS',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 15,
                                        fontFamily: 'assets/fonts/LeferiBase',
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Tab(
                                    child: Text(
                                      'MEMBERS',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 15,
                                        fontFamily: 'assets/fonts/LeferiBase',
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 20),
                        const Expanded(
                          child: TabBarView(children: [
                            EventsScreen(),
                            MembersScreen(),
                          ]),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is my GridView code

```
import ...

class EventsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const EventsScreen({super.key});

  @override
  _EventsScreenState createState() {
    return _EventsScreenState();
  }
}

class _EventsScreenState extends State<EventsScreen> {
  List<Nfts> nfts = [];
  bool isLoading = true;
  NftsProviders nftsProvider = NftsProviders();

  Future initNfts() async {
    nfts = await nftsProvider.getNfts();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initNfts().then((_) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return isLoading
        ? const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          )
        : Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
            child: GridView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: nfts.length,
              gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 3),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => const NFTDetailPage()),
                      );
                    },
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 30,
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(nfts[index].meta_image),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried wrapping your expanded widget inside a Sized box with height and width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `expanded` inside `SingleChildScrollView`  which is giving you error.

Try removing the `expanded` widget wrap from `tabView`.

Change this

```
Expanded(
  child: TabBarView(children: [
       EventsScreen(),
       MembersScreen(),
      ]),
```

to

```
TabBarView(children: [
       EventsScreen(),
       MembersScreen(),
      ]
```

Comment: If I delete 'Expanded' I get another error. The error is:

''' ======== Exception caught by rendering library ================================== ===================
The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height.'''

If I wrap the EventsScreen widget composed of GridView with a container and give it a specific height, the GridView with infinite height is cut off.